# I can't get the sum of grandtotal in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to get the grand total. Just like the link of the picture below, it only display the amount input and display it beside the other amount. How can I add the grand total.

this is the link of the picture. please click.
[image]

```
grandtotal = 0;
$('input[name^=amount]').each(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    grandtotal += $(this).val();
});
$("#grandtotal").html(grandtotal);
```

Answer (score 4):

you're adding strings together, rather than numbers. If you want a number to display, you'll need to use:

```
//javascript
grandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

or, since you added [php] tag:

```
//php
grandtotal += floatval( $your_variable );
```